# Can I reference a referenced library in Visual Studio 2010 (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have to change some used libraries quite a lot. I am storing the changed libraries in a new folder. To use these new libraries I have to change the references in projects which uses these. Because my solution contains 15 projects which have to use the libraries, I have to change the references in every project. But that really s****! Is there a simple way to just change the reference path in a single project and the other projects are referencing the references? So that I have to change the references only once?

Comment: Nothing that I know of, but since project files are in XML format, a simple xml transformation of all csproj in all subfolders can do the job. You can easily write a simple project that does that.

Answer (score 2):

Use reference path tab in project properties. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6taasyc6.aspx

Comment: I think flashflail has a problem with changing references in many solutions. Since Reference path is also set in project properties, that's not much of a tradeoff.

Answer (score 1):

If the library is in your solution, you can add it as a "project reference" in all the projects that depend on it. Thus, changes will automatically be accessible as soon as the library changes.

Comment: Sorry, but the library is not inside the solution.

Comment: Maybe it should be, if you have that many projects depending on it. If that is not at all possible, you could write a wrapper class. This could forward calls to the library class. Thus, you would have a single entry point.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think  such a 'reference to a reference' mechanism exists. You can ease your pain a bit by opening your project in Notepad, copying th desired reference string and then using some third-party search and replace software which can traverse through all your projects and change the reference for you.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a shared library folder.

```
/src
  /lib (shared folder)
    /mylibraries (for ease of use copy your newest libraries here)
```

When you decide you are going to increment you can move your old libraries to a new folder and replace them with your new libraries.

```
 /src
      /lib (shared folder)
        /mylibraries (copy from here)
           /3-1-2011  (to here)
```